# How do you send push notifications to a Rust app?

Tags: rust, push-notification, tauri

I'm building a desktop app with Tauri and I need to send pure-data push notifications to them from an AWS Lambda function. I was previously using FCM and listening from my Electron app with the [push-receiver Node library](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/push-receiver) that painstakingly reverse engineered the GCM message protocol. But I don't see anything similar for Rust. And from what I can tell WNS is only for apps in the Microsoft Store, and I'm not planning on requiring my users go through that.

Has this been tackled yet? So far the only route forward I can see is trying to port push-receiver to Rust.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the [fcm-push-listener](https://crates.io/crates/fcm-push-listener) crate to do this. I used the push-receiver and @aracna/fcm libraries as reference for which endpoints to call with each protocol.

```rust
use fcm_push_listener::FcmPushListener;

let firebase_app_id = "1:1001234567890:android:2665128ba997ffab830a24";
let firebase_project_id = "myapp-1234567890123";
let firebase_api_key = "aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTu01234_aBcD0123456789";
let vapid_key = "BClpBSn3aL7aZ2JZxWB0RrdBqw-5-A7xLoeoxBWdcjxnby4MFvTG8nIa1KHmSY2-cmCAySR4PoCcOZtW18aXNw1";

let registration = fcm_push_listener::register(
    firebase_app_id,
    firebase_project_id,
    firebase_api_key,
    vapid_key).await?;

// Send registration.fcm_token to the server to allow it to send push messages to you.

let mut listener = FcmPushListener::create(
    registration,
    |message: FcmMessage| {
        println!("Message JSON: {}", message.payload_json);
        println!("Persistent ID: {:?}", message.persistent_id);
    },
    vec!["0:1677356129944104%7031b2e6f9fd7ecd".to_owned()]);
listener.connect().await?;
```